# POST request with multiple params

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make an API call in my nodejs file, but am unable to do so. I continue to get an error

> Incorrect number of arguments

in my `http.post()` call.

This is the code I am trying to use to call the data:

```
checkHash(username, password) {
                return new Promise(resolve => {
                        //var inData = ("/" + username + "/" + password);
                        console.log("below is username");
                        console.log(username);
                        console.log("below is password");
                        console.log(password);

                        this.http.post('http://url/checkHash/', username, '/' + password)
                        .subscribe(res => {
                                console.log("checkHash");
                                console.log(res);
                                resolve(res);
                        });
                });
        }
```

I have the server endpoint running so when you call a post like so in postman it returns what I need: `http://url/getHash/admin/admin` the first parameter is supposed to be username, next is password.

Comment: there are tons of examples on the internet. for example: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/

Answer (score 3):

The commas that you're using in your `post` are creating 3 parameters to the `post` function, but you need to pass the URL as one parameter:

```
this.http.post('http://url/checkHash/' + username + '/' + password).subscribe(...)
```